# Good Men are for Good Women and Good Women are for Good Men

Tags: nikah

If this statement is true then why do we see sometimes a really good person has been paired up (married) to a really bad person?

Comment: I believe you misunderstand the verse(24:26), it's not that good men are for good women etc, it means good statements are for good men and good men are for good statements. This explains the meaning (tafsir ibn kathir) http://www.alim.org/library/quran/AlQuran-tafsir/TIK/24/26

Comment: @AbdelRahmanShamel ah ok that makes sense. Jazak Allah Khair. It's just that I see people posting that quote with picture of a man and woman so I thought the same as them that it refers to the husband and wife.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot take one verse of the Quran in isolation and derive a ruling from it. The fundamental rule in understanding Quran is

`القرآن یفسّر بعضه بعضاً`

[Often one part of Quran is explained by another part of it]

> Allah sets forth, for an example to the Unbelievers, the wife of Noah
>   and the wife of Lut: they were (respectively) under two of our
>   righteous servants, but they were false to their (husbands), and they
>   profited nothing before Allah on their account, but were told: "Enter
>   ye the Fire along with (others) that enter!" ([10](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.yusufali/66:10))

How can we take "good women for good men and so on," in the literal sense when Allah (swt) Himself sets forth examples of **odd pairs**?

If you search the Tafasir, most exegetes don't even translate it as "women for men," but rather "bad talk."

`الكلمات الخبيثات من القول للخبيثين من الرجال`

This is in context of the false accusations against Ayesha (ra).

Some others who have interpreted it as "women for men," also qualify it like

`وما ذلك إلا لإِظهار منصب الرسول صلى الله عليه وسلم وإعلاء منزلته`

That is to say that the verse does not set a rule but it is meant to vindicate Ayesha (ra) and elevate the status of Prophet Muhammad (puh).

Lastly, there is also an opinion that the verse is related to

`ٱلزَّانِي لاَ يَنكِحُ إِلاَّ زَانِيَةً` (this itself is not understood as a rule)

and in this case one would say that "bad" (Khabith) means adulterer or adulteress and not just any conceivable mismatch of piety between the spouses.

Comment: ok now even if it means good talk for good people and bad talk for bad people, sometimes people talk bad about good people and even talk good about bad people. We might not know who is good or who is bad. I agree, But we do know that the Prophet (saw) was a good person but people even now talk bad about him.

Comment: You are missing the point completely. God is not defining a universal sociological rule here. Don't look at it like you would the laws of motion. Its more like how we tell our children to avoid bad-talk by saying "bad talk is for bad people"

Comment: no but we are told that everything in the Qur'an is the truth and it does not say anywhere to tell your children this. Yeah ok we are teaching them discipline by telling them this but it is still a false statement. And if it does not apply to everyone then why is it in the Quran since the Quran is for the whole humanity so everyone should be able to relate?

Comment: I never said anything about the verse being a command to teach children; I suggest you re-read critically. Quran is truth but it is not a book of **literal truth assertions**. Language of Quran has metaphors, allegories, proverbs, literal statements and even cryptic text like "الم" (No one knows the meaning of الم). My suggestion would  be to always look up the Tafsir of an Ayah by many Exegetes who were much better skilled.